# How to set a query string value in javascript then reload a page

Tags: javascript

How do I add a query string value to a URL, then refresh that page?

The current url looks like: /foo/bar

I want to reload as /foo/bar?tabIndex=4

```
    function onSomethingComplete() {

    window.location.search = "tabIndex=4";
    window.location.reload();

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: window.location.href += "tabIndex=4";

Comment: `window.location.search` already does a reload itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to do something like this:

```
function onSomethingComplete() {

    var url = window.location
    url += "?tabIndex=4"
    window.location = url

}
```

Comment: as long as I added the window.location.search; it worked, thanks!